# How Can I Configure ActiveMQ In Geronimo To Use MySQL Persistence?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, geronimo

I was able to configure this quite easily in TomEE, but have not been able to find a reference that describes how to configure the resource adapter to use mysql instead of the default. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

look on http://tomee.apache.org/jms-resources-and-mdb-container.html (part Internal ActiveMQ Broker with JDBC Persistence)